# How to get Map as an object in javascript ES6?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, es6-class

My Class is using es6 to create an map object at node level, 
using Map()--"set" function.When class is called i want the map object to get converted to normal json type structure. I am using moongoose to retreive the data from database.

```
res.json(MapObject);
```

After using this res.json whole content inside parent node is getting empty.

```
{success:{},
 error:{},
redirectMe:false}
```

Have Map Object like this

```
{
  success: 
   Map {
     'String1' => 'true',
     'Object1' => [ [Object],
                    [Object],
                    [Object],
                    [Object],
                    [Object]
                  ]
     'String2' => 100 
     }
  error: Map {},
  redirectMe: false 
}
```

I want to get result as an Object but when I tries to get it not able to get anything

Wanted something like

```
{
  success: 
    {
     'String1' : 'true',
     'Object1' : [ [Object],
                    [Object],
                    [Object],
                    [Object],
                    [Object]
                  ]
     'String2' : 100 
     }
  error: {},
  redirectMe: false 
}
```

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: *"...converted to normal json type structure..."*  JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON. Do you mean a plain object? `{}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better way to convert map to object

```
let jsonResponse = {};
            for(let [key,val] of MapObject.entries()){
                jsonResponse[key]= val;
            }

console.log(jsonResponse);
```

Answer (score 21):

You can convert a map to an object easily using a native JS function:

```
Object.fromEntries(map);
```

Note: This function is part of the ECMAScript 10 spec and is supported by Node.js 12+ and Chrome 73+, could also be polyfilled to work on older platforms using this [plugin](https://github.com/feross/fromentries)

```js
const map = new Map();
// Setting up some sample data
map.set("foo", "bar");
map.set("pets", ["Fido", "Foobar", "Al"]);
// Convert map to object
const convertedMap = Object.fromEntries(map);

console.log(convertedMap);
```

Answer (score 13):

Now that JavaScript has [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) (added in ES2019, easily polyfilled), this is a one-liner:

```
const obj = Object.fromEntries(map);
```

Live Example:

```js
const map = new Map();
map.set("string1", true);
map.set("someArray", [{a:1}, {b:2}, {c:3}]);
map.set("string2", 100);

const obj = Object.fromEntries(map);

console.log(obj);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

The `Map`'s keys must be strings or Symbols, or things that can be meaningfully converted to strings, since property keys in objects can only be strings or Symbols.

---

**Previous answer:** If you have a `Map` and you want to convert it to a plain object, that's easily done **if** the `Map`'s keys are strings or Symbols or something (numbers, for instance) that can meaningfully be converted to strings.

You just loop over its keys:

```
const obj = {};
for (const key of map.keys()) {
  obj[key] = map.get(key);
}
```

Live Example:

```js
const map = new Map();
map.set("string1", true);
map.set("someArray", [{a:1}, {b:2}, {c:3}]);
map.set("string2", 100);

const obj = {};
for (const key of map.keys()) {
  obj[key] = map.get(key);
}

console.log(obj);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

That said, as [Kunal noted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43936171/157247), it might make more sense to use `entries` (and you don't need `.entries()`, you can just use `of map` to get the default iterator, which is for entries).

Comment: This is just exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @jwehrle - :-) Things have moved on since the original answer above; I've updated it to show `Object.fromEntries`, which was added in ES2019.

Comment: For some reason I have not been able to figure out Object.fromEntries is throwing a type error in this situation. So I went with a more basic method.

Comment: @jwehrle - Huh. Well, whatever works. :-) But if you want to know why, post a question with your code and point me at it. (Or of course, someone else may get there first). Happy coding!

Answer (score 4):

One-liner to convert Map to plain Object:

```
Object.assign({}, ...[...m.entries()].map(([k, v]) => ({[k]: v})))
```